# split string into two array on behalf of odd or even

Tags: c#

i have this array:

```
 string[] words = new string[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
```

I want to split it in two arrays depending if the index is even or odd, like this:

```
string[] odd="a,c,e";
string [] even="b,d,f";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds not a hard problem. Have you tried _anything_? Clearly, you can iterate with a `for` statement char by char and from zero to less than `words.Length` and check it's index is even or odd. If it is even, add even array, if it is odd, add odd array.

Comment: Start with `String.Split()` to get `string wordList = { "a", "b", ... }, `

Comment: Also, note that even your declaration is invalid: `"a,b,c,d,e,f"` is *not* a `string[]`.

Comment: It looks more like combining an array into two strings (except `odd` and `even` are declared like arrays for some reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Enumerable.Where` with the index and the remainder `%`:

```
string[] even =  words.Where((str, ix) => ix % 2 == 0).ToArray();
string[]  odd =  words.Where((str, ix) => ix % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

Another way using `ToLookup`:

```
var evenOddIndexLookup = words.Select((str, index) => new { str, index }).ToLookup(x => x.index % 2);
string[] even = evenOddIndexLookup[0].Select(x => x.str).ToArray();
string[]  odd = evenOddIndexLookup[1].Select(x => x.str).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var odd = words.Where(item =>Array.IndexOf(words,item) % 2 ==1).ToArray();
 var even = words.Where(item =>Array.IndexOf(words,item) % 2 ==0).ToArray();
```